# Instantiate Object at mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a script which was supposed to instantiate gameobject according to mouse position but something has went wrong. And it is only being instantiated at one position and in the middle of the screen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineInstantiater : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject lineprefab;
    private GameObject linehandler;
    private Vector3 mousepos;

    void Update(){
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            linehandler = Instantiate (lineprefab,Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject ;
            linehandler.transform.position = mousepos;
        }
    }

}
```

Please tell me what is wrong with my script.

Comment: Hi, what's your question? What went wrong? If you get any error, please post it.

Comment: @Programmer Check it is edited. I always forgot to mention that

Comment: Sorry, but we don't know what your problem is. What do you mean by "instantiated at one position."? The prefab is not instantiating where the mouse arrow is? What type of OBject is this? UI, 2D or 3D object? I suggest you post screenshot too

Comment: @Programmer not instantiating where the mouse arrow is. too keep it simple

Comment: The answer depends of what type of object it is. UI(Image,RawImage component), 2D(SpriteRenderer) or 3D(MeshRenderer) object?

Comment: @Programmer 2D object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Input.mousePosition` does not have z-axis because there is only x and y axis for mouse coordinate. The `z` axis is simply `0` therefore returning wrong position when `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` is used.

You need to do `Input.mousePosition;`, manually modify it's z-axis value to be anything `> 0`. Usually, `10` is fine for this but you can modify it if it is not enough for you. After that, you can then pass that modified `Vector3` to the `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousepos)` function.

```
public GameObject lineprefab;
private GameObject linehandler;
private Vector3 mousepos;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        mousepos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousepos.z = 10;

        mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousepos);
        linehandler = Instantiate(lineprefab, mousepos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
public GameObject lineprefab;
private GameObject linehandler;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray rayCast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        linehandler = Instantiate(lineprefab, rayCast.GetPoint(10), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

*Not related:*

I noticed that you are using `Input.GetMouseButton`. You probably want `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` as `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` is called once until the key is released. `Input.GetMouseButton` is repeatedly called when the pressed key is held down and you can easily create thousands of objects with that.